# Is there any way that to use mysql Dump file as a database source in android

Tags: android, mysql

Is there any way that to use mysql dump file as a database source file in android? Actually, I have accounts software with database in Mysql. Now I want to read that database file on android. (Either by creating a mysql dump file or by using that dump file in android or is there any other best way to do it?)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  You could theoretically go line by line and run the commands in SQLite.  The issue will be if the dump file contains any commands or syntax that isn't supported by SQLite, in which case you'll have issues.